# Instalation of Intershop 7.9 failing on missing version for demo cartridges

Tags: intershop

I'm trying to install a demo shop of Intershop version 7.9 but i'm failing to get it working. When I run "gradlew deployServer" I'm getting an error on all dependencies of the first demo shop cartridge:

`Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app_sf_responsive:compile'.
 Could not resolve com.intershop.business:ac_ecircle:.
  Required by:
      nl.test.testproject:app_sf_responsive:1.0.0-LOCAL
    No version for module 'com.intershop.business:ac_ecircle' in project properties and no version declared in dependency. Consider adding a version or filter property to 'C:\projects\test7.9\projects\testproject\gradle.properties'`

I have followed the complete Intershop manual Setup CI Infrastructure but there is one point I don't know exactly what to do, that's with the new versioning plugin.
It is in chapter 6.2.5, any one have an idea how to configure that?

Comment: Are you using "Cookbook - Setup CI Infrastructure"?

Comment: I also tried to install a fresh ish 7.9. I followed the Setup CI Infrastructure Cookbook, but can't get further than step 7. Can't get the corporate-distribution to upload to nexus.

Comment: Yes, I am using the Setup CI Infrastructure. I finished the whole setup and still ran into problems. I then tried to re-add the corporate-distribution zip file and that failed.

Answer (score 1):

After loads of tinkering and mails back and forth with Intershop support I found a solution.

My alterations are in section 7.2.4 of the Setup CI Infrastructure of Intershop:

https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/279D85#Cookbook-SetupCIInfrastructure-CorporateArtifactsRecipe:SetupCIBuildforCorporateArtifacts

I Made sure the corporate distribution is unique since I have more that 1 Intershop installation. Otherwise the upload to Nexus(in my case) will still fail.

In the build.gradle of the corporate distibution folder added disableSCM = true in the scm.version section. It now looks like this:

```
scm {
    version {
        type = 'threeDigits'
        increment = 'MAJOR'
        patternDigits = 1
        disableSCM = true
        initialVersion = '2.0.0'
    }
}
```

If this is not added I got a bad request httpstatus 400 from Nexus because it tried to upload it as a snapshot while the distribution repository is a release repository.

Another problem is the distributionURL in the project/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
All Nexus repository URL's are build up with < repoBaseURL > + repositories/snapshots, but the distributionURL is missing the repositories part.

After applied those changes it worked for me.